# Flash xml fed scroller - controling right left arrows issues

Tags: xml, flash, button, scroll, ticker

i need some hands on controlling scrolling text with 2 buttons left and right data fed by xml .

my file structure is like this:

main file:          **bg.swf**
ticker file :       **tikcer.swf**
buttons file:       **scrolling.swf**
ActionScript file:  **xml_ticker.as**

**bg.swf** is calling ticker on 0 level and scrolling buttons on level 1 ... thats cuz ticker text coming from xml wont go over the right and left arrow buttons .... now my question is:

i want to control ticker thats running from right to left .... on clicking left arrow it shud speed up and on release it shud go back to normal speed ..

and on right arrow it shud go opposite direction and on release it she go its orginal direction and speed.

thanx alot for help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Flash/ActionScript you're programming against, but if it's for ActionScript 3 [this](http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/actionscript/keypress-for-as3-96851.html) should be of some help.

For AS 2, you can try [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001550.html).